# Why isn't source control working when I use a workspace in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, xcode5

Normally I just create a new project, select the option to keep it under source control, and everything works.

Today I tried using a workspace, and it doesn't work. Here is what I did:

1. File->Xcode->New WorkSpace. (Create the workspace in a new folder). hit Save.
2. File->New Project->iOS->Single View Application->Next
3. Enter product name etc, Next
4. Make sure "Create git repository on My Mac" is checked. Select the folder where the workspace is saved. Choose "Add to"->The workspace you created. Hit Create.
5. Type some stuff into app delegate. Build.  Save file.
6. Try to commit in source control --> Can't! All the options are greyed out. Even though changes are made to app delegate, the "m" symbol does not appear near it.

**How do I correctly set up my workspace so I can use source control ? What is wrong with my set up ?**

EDIT: Trying to add new files doesn't make the "A" symbol show up near the new files either. Clearly source control isn't on.
If I create a project that isn't part of the workspace, source control works fine.

EDIT: Navigating to the folder directory and running `git status` , gives the following message:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

**Why wasn't a git repository created ? and how do I get it to work?**

EDIT: I deleted my project from the workspace. Closed the workspace. Created the project again outside the workspace. Closed the project. Dragged the project into the workspace, and now the project is both part of he workspace, and it is under source control.  Can't tell why it didn't work when I created the project within the workspace.

EDIT: As I don't know the reason why source control didn't work when I created the project within the workspace, I'm leaving this open in case someone has an answer, or knows if it is a known bug.

Comment: I've just come up with this problem too. First time using workspaces and am a little confused about why there is no source code repository.

Comment: Just as a quick note to anyone with a similar problem with their Xcode Bot, you can remove all the directories inside the BotRuns folder and it will begin integrating again. This was for error : `Error in Git checkout Error Domain=CSBotSCMAction Code=-1000 "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your .git directory is not inside the main workspace directory. Enable hidden file view in Finder and see where your .git directory is. 
Xcode makes it rather confusing working with workspaces, since it does enforce any logical directory structure. 
You can try using IDEs such as AppCode to give you better idea, you can get a free 30 day version of it from JetBrain's website.